# Python list assignation

Tags: python

I've got this code

```
class coordenates:
    x = 0             
    y = 0            

coor = coordenates()
coor.x=0
coor.y=0

list = []
list.append(coor)
list.append(coor)
```

Now, the problem is that when I update

```
list[0].x=100
```

it is also modifing `list[1].x` somehow!

```
print str(list[0].x)
>> 100
print str(list[1].x)
>> 100
```

which must remain in `0` since I haven't update it. Is `append()` creating the same object pointing in the same position in memory in positions 0 and 1? why creating 2 different objects solves the problem?

Comment: You are appending the same object to the list twice. If you change it it will change at both indexes.

Comment: `append` isn't creating the same object in the same memory position, *you* are explicitely appending the same object.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In your current code, `x` and `y` are class-level attributes. I suspect that you want them to be instance-level attributes. If so, set them in `__init__()`:

```
class Coordinates:

    def __init__(self):
        self.x = 0             
        self.y = 0
```

More important, if you append the same `coor` to the list twice, any mutation of the `coor` will be reflected in "both" coordinates (because the list is just holding a reference to the same underlying coordinate in both positions of the list). Maybe you want something like this instead, where you create two independent coordinate instances?

```
list = []
list.append(Coordinates())
list.append(Coordinates())
```

You can see an illustration of your problem with this code:

```
c = Coordinates()
cs = []
cs.append(c)
cs.append(c)

for c in cs:
    print id(c)  # Both elements of the list refer to the same object.
```

Comment: Probably the best way. It might also be worth mentioning the `copy` module.

Comment: So if I do `temp= 0,   list.append(temp), list.append(temp)` list[0]=100 will modify both positions as well? btw amazing response! I implemented `list.append(Coordinates())` as the way to go.

Comment: @Joe Well ... that example is a bit different. You are **assigning** an entirely new object (an integer `100`) to the `[0]` element. In the initial example, we were appending the same object (`coor`) to the list twice, and then mutating the underlying object.